# Applying transition effects to slow down opening of submenu when menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a vertical menu with dropdown when user clicks on parent menu child elements in that parent are shown...The child elements are opening fast i want to slow down the speed when the child elements are shown.

The is the demo i have created http://codepen.io/raju9642182468/pen/grWZPa

How can i slowdown the menu opening speed..Somebody help me how to make that

```
   function showmenu(elem) {
        // Clear any currently open menu
        var elementClicked = event.target;           
        if (elementClicked.className != 'sectionMenu')
            return;
        var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");

        if (openMenu) {
            openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
            // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
            if (openMenu === elem) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
        // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
        if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
            elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
        }                      
    }

    function focusStyle(elem) {
        if (document.getElementById("anchor") != null) {
            document.getElementById("anchor").removeAttribute("id");
        }
        var anchorClicked = event.target;
        if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
            elem.setAttribute("id", "anchor");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you against using jQuery?

Comment: if you use css transition you can add **transition-duration** property in your css

Comment: If you are not against using jquery you can acheive this accordion style menu with **jquery accordion**: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Your demo isn't working in firefox. On clicking menu item, error is `event is not defined`. change `showmenu(this)` to `showmenu(event,this)` and `function showmenu(elem)` to `function showmenu(event,elem)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample how you can do using CSS `transition` and `max-height`

To be noted, since animate height can't be done using `height: auto`, this uses `max-height`. The trick to make it work, is to set it to a value which will always be more than the actual menu list.

I used 400px in below sample and by altering this and the duration, one can get pretty close to a perfect animation.

```js
function showmenu(event,elem) {
  // Clear any currently open menu
  var elementClicked = event.target;           
  if (elementClicked.className != 'sectionMenu')
    return;
  var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");

  if (openMenu) {
    openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
    // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
    if (openMenu === elem) {
      return;
    }
  }
  // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
  // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
  if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
    elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
  }                      
}

function focusStyle(event,elem) {
  if (document.getElementById("anchor") != null) {
    document.getElementById("anchor").removeAttribute("id");
  }
  var anchorClicked = event.target;
  if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
    elem.setAttribute("id", "anchor");
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
}

nav{
  height:100%;
}
#nav1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;      
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;        
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:0;        
}
ul li {   
  line-height:30px;   
  position: relative;
  color:#ff6a00;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #00ff21;
}

#main-menu > li.active > a {
  color: #b6ff00;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;

}
nav #nav1 #activeMenu .sectionMenu{
  background-color: rgb(69,199,77);         
}
ul li a{
  padding: 0.5em 1.25em 0.5em 3.125em;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  color:#585858;
  padding-left:50px;      
}
ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-size:1.5em; 
}  
ul ul {
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul ul li a {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  padding: 0.875em 1.25em 0.875em 0.625em;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  height: 1.875em;  
}
#activeMenu ul {
  max-height: 400px;
}

li.sectionMenu:before {
  /*content: '\2795'; 
  content: '\1401'; 
  content: '\2206'; */     
  height:10px;
  font-weight:20px;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #000000;
  text-rendering:auto;
  float: right;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:25px; 
}

#activeMenu {
  background-color: #ffffff;     
}
#anchor {
  background-color:#e7e7e7;
}

ul li ul li{
  padding-left:80px;
}

ul ul li a i {
  padding-right:123px;
}
#buildIcon{
  right: 190px;     
}

span{
  float:right;
}
ul ul li i {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav1">

  <li onclick="showmenu(event,this)" class="sectionMenu dropdown">
    <a class="sectionMenu">   
      Class !
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a>                              
        A

        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active-class"  >
        <a>
          b
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active-class" >
        <a >
          c
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active-class" >
        <a>
          d
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showmenu(event,this)" class="sectionMenu dropdown">
    <a class="sectionMenu">                    
      Class  II
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>1</a> </li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>2 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>3</a> </li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>4 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>5 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>6</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li onclick="showmenu(event,this)" class="sectionMenu dropdown">
    <a class="sectionMenu">                    
      Class  III
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>1 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>2 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a> 3 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>4 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>5 </a></li>
      <li  class="active-class"> <a>6 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but your suggested #activeMenu ul {
  max-height: 400px;
} ,but we required 100% height... it can possible .

Comment: @RajaReddy I showed you the technique how to, now you can adjust and add your own values.

Comment: thanks i put them min-height:10px; max-height:1800px; its working ,future any problem can give it .. or increase the side menu list items ...